# Invalid column sqlException in Linq query after update to Core 2.0

Tags: linq, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I just updated my API application to ASP.Net Core 2.0 as well as EF Core accordingly.

The following query used to work fine before:

```
IList<myDTO> allRecords = _context.myModel                               
                                .Select(item => new myDTO()
                                {
                                   recordId = item.myId,                                   
                                    recordName = item.myName                                  
                                })
                                .OrderBy(o=>o.recordName)                                
                                .Skip(limit * (page - 1))
                                .Take(limit)
                                .ToList();

public class myModel
    {       
        [Key]       
        public int myId { get; set; }       
        public string myName { get; set; }       
    }

public class myDTO
    {      
        public int recordId { get; set; }      
        public string recordName { get; set; }      
    }
```

After the update I always get a

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'recordName '.'
```

If i remove the GrouBy

```
IList<myDTO> allRecords = _context.myModel                               
                                .Select(item => new myDTO()
                                {
                                   recordId = item.myId,                                   
                                    recordName = item.myName                                  
                                })                                                             
                                .Skip(limit * (page - 1))
                                .Take(limit)
                                .ToList();
```

or the recordName field

```
 IList<myDTO> allRecords = _context.myModel                               
                                .Select(item => new myDTO()
                                {
                                   recordId = item.myId            
                                })
                                .OrderBy(o=>o.recordName)                                
                                .Skip(limit * (page - 1))
                                .Take(limit)
                                .ToList();
```

or the Skip

```
IList<myDTO> allRecords = _context.myModel                               
                                    .Select(item => new myDTO()
                                    {
                                       recordId = item.myId,                                   
                                        recordName = item.myName                                  
                                    })
                                    .OrderBy(o=>o.recordName)
                                    .Take(limit)
                                    .ToList();
```

,it works fine but I need my recordName field and skipped and ordered...

Would you have any advices of why I get such a error after my move to Core 2.0? The Linq query seems to be perfectly fine

Sylvain

Comment: Where is the GroupBy in your original query? Or did you mean if you remove the OrderBy.

Comment: Why? Usually it's called regression bug. Anytime you get something like this, check/post it in their issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you all, I have checked the EFCore team on Githuib and it seesm to be aknown issue which should be solved in the next 2.1.0 version: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10570

Comment: You should try not tu use Entity Framework at all. I can swear that's the most buggy piece of software I've ever used...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `OrderBy` on your table field `myName` first and then do the `select`.

```
IList<myDTO> allRecords = _context.myModel   
                                .OrderBy(o => o.myName)                              
                                .Select(item => new myDTO()
                                {
                                    recordId = item.myId,                                   
                                    recordName = item.myName                                  
                                })                                                              
                                .Skip(limit * (page - 1))
                                .Take(limit)
                                .ToList();
```

Check out if this approach works.

Comment: Thank you, I also tried this option but get exactly the same issue